# Delimiter for end of file string

Tags: c, string, delimiter, strtok

I am trying to split up a comma delimited string from a file. I am able to split the string by all of the commas but how do I get the last bit of the string?

For example a line from the file : "cat,dog,mouse"

How do I tokenize the last part "mouse" from the string? What delimiter should I use or is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

You  don't need to use any seperate delimiter. If you use `,` as  delimiter with [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok), by parsing the same input *string*, on each iteration, you'll get a token like

- cat
- dog
- mouse
- NULL (indicates no more token).

Just to add clarification, quoting the man page,

> Delimiter bytes at the start or end of the string are ignored

So, even if you add the *string* terminator `null` to the delimiter string, it will not make any changes in the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I tokenize the last part "mouse" from the string?

In C, strings are terminated with a null (`\0`) character. So the last part of your string really looks like this:

```
mouse\0
```

or, in hex:

```
6d 6f 75 73 65 00
```

But you don't need to do anything special to deal with a null-terminated string. All the functions in any standard library and pretty much any other C code you'll find understand that a null byte ends a string, so functions that split up strings, copy strings, catenate strings, etc. all work fine without any other "end of string" delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `,` as delimiter in `strtok()`.

```
int main()
{
  char string[] = "cat,dog,mouse";
  const char s[2] = ",";
  char *token;

  token = strtok(string, s);

  while( token != NULL ) 
  {
     printf( " %s\n", token );

     token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last delimiter is the terminating zero.:)

Here is an example how a character array can be split into substrings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] =  "cat, dog, mouse";

    char *p = strtok( s, ", " );

    while ( p != NULL )
    {
        puts( p );

        p = strtok( NULL, ", " );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
cat
dog
mouse
```

I aslo used as a delimiter blank character.

Take into account that strtok changes the original string. So you may not use it with string literals.